# Make field in admin read only dependent on user

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to give a staff user change access to only his own user record in the django admin but to also have readonly view of the records of the other staff users. I could easily do this by defining the fields in the get_readonly_fields method. But whenever I add a field to the model I have to add this there too (and if I forget its big trouble).

So I tried this (found somewhere at SO):

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    my_readonly_fields= list(set([field.name for field in self.opts.local_fields]
```

However, this will make excluded fields reappear (it seams that readonly fields are always shown) which I do not want.

Is there a way to get the valid fields? The get_fields method I cannot call, because it will try to call the get_readonly_fields method. Or is there a generally better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not using [`ModelAdmin.get_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) or [`ModelAdmin.get_fieldsets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fieldsets) to generate the list of fields, you can just walk through the `self.fields` or `self.fieldsets` and exclude those from the `readonly_fields` list.

Specifically:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    my_readonly_fields = [
        field.name
        for field in self.opts.local_fields
        if field.name not in self.fields]

    return list(set(my_readonly_fields))
```

Comment: self.field is always None - I am using the get_form method, which calls get_fields - is it because of that?

Comment: I just noted that whatever I do in the get_readonly_fields method (e.g. just return a list with one field) the excluded fields will reappear.